# Add pairs greater than n filter

Tags: dictionary, filter, sml

I am new to SML.  I am trying to write a function using map and filter to add pairs from a list where x and y of the pair are greater than n.  The code compiles without any errors, however, when I execute the function `addPairsGreaterThan 3 [(1,2), (3,3), (1,1)]`, I receive an empty list as output.

My SML code is listed below:

```
fun addPairsGreaterThan n intPairs =
  let
    val helperList = filter(fn (x,y) => x > n andalso y > n) (intPairs)
    fun addPairs (x,y) = x+y
  in
    map addPairs helperList
  end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *[...]* add pairs from a list where x and y of the pair are greater than n.
>
> *[...]* `addPairsGreaterThan 3 [(1,2), (3,3), (1,1)]`, I receive an empty list as output.

None of those pairs have both (or any) parts greater than 3. So `[]` seems right.

Your function appears to work, although:

- You're referring to a function `filter`. Do you mean `List.filter`?
- You can rename `intPairs` to `pairs`; [Hungarian notation is bad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102689/what-is-the-benefit-of-not-using-hungarian-notation).
- The `addPairs` helper function is equivalent to and can be replaced by `op+`.
- The `helperList` temporary binding is unnecessary.

Here's a rewritten version:

```
fun addPairsGreaterThan n pairs =
    map op+ (List.filter (fn (x,y) => x > n andalso y > n) pairs)
```

Since this definition takes the form of *f(x) = g(h(x))*, you can define it as *f = g o h* where

- *g* is `map op+` and
- *h* is `List.filter (fn (x,y) => x > n andalso y > n)`.

The parentheses are not necessary, so this might look a little convoluted:

```
fun addPairsGreaterThan n =
    map op+  o  List.filter (fn (x,y) => x > n andalso y > n)
```